# Does sleep() interfere with scanf()?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, sleep, scanf

I have two threads

`xThread` : Continuously Prints X on the console

`inputThread`: Gets input from the stdin

The continuous printing stops when the user enters 'C' or 'c'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#define S sleep(0)

int read_c = 0;
pthread_mutex_t read_c_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* inputThread_fn(void* arg)
{
char inputChar;

while(1)
{
    S;

    printf("\nChecking input");
    scanf("%c",&inputChar);
    if(inputChar=='C' || inputChar == 'c')
    {
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex); /*<--This must be _lock ?
    because with the use of trylock even If i don't aquire a lock I go ahead and modify
    the variable?*/
        read_c = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);        
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

}

void* xThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        S;
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
    if(!read_c)
    printf(" X");
    else
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
    }

}

void* yThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        S;
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
    if(!read_c)
    printf(" Y");
    else
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
    }

}


int main()
{
pthread_t xThread,yThread,inputThread;

pthread_create(&xThread,NULL,xThread_fn,NULL);
pthread_create(&inputThread,NULL,inputThread_fn,NULL);

pthread_join(xThread,NULL);
pthread_join(inputThread,NULL);

return 0;   
}
```

When I use `sleep(1)` the threads are spawned and [irrespective of which thread is started first]  when the program reaches `scanf` in `inputThread` it halts for the user input and the code does not proceed until I enter an input.

When I execute the code with `sleep(0)`, `scanf` does not halt for the input, it keeps printing 'X' until  I enter 'C' or 'c'

Does `sleep()` interfere with `scanf` in someway?

**Note:** I am aware of `select` being used for non-blocking input. I have tried the same too and the code runs fine. I just want to know in the above case why inconsistent behaviour arises?

---

Update (Using `trylock`)

---

```
 void* inputThread_fn(void* arg)
{
char inputChar;

    while(1)
    {
    S;
    scanf("%c",&inputChar);
        if(inputChar=='C' || inputChar == 'c')
        {
            pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
                read_c = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);        
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
}

void* xThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
    S;
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
        if(!read_c)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            printf(" X");
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    fflush(stdout); 
    }
}

void* yThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
    S;
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
        if(!read_c)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            printf(" Z");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because using no sleep could cause one task to block another? At least under some circumstances this could be the problem. Sleep ensures proper task switches on some platforms.

Comment: @Matthias: I think that's fairly archaic these days, especially if we're talking about POSIX threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you don't see output is because you're not flushing the buffer.

The reason you don't need to flush the buffer with `sleep(0)` is because the writer thread writes so much data that the buffer fills up and is automatically flushed.

```
#define SLEEP_TIME 1

void* xThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    while (1) {
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&read_c_mutex);
        if (read_c) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
        printf(" X");
        fflush(stdout); // <-- necessary
    }
}
```

### Don't use `pthread_mutex_trylock()`

Don't use `pthread_mutex_trylock()` here.  It's wrong.

The difference between `lock()` and `trylock()` is that `lock()` will always succeed<sup>1</sup> but `trylock()` will sometimes fail.  That's why it's called "try".

Since `trylock()` sometimes fails, you have to handle the case where it failed.  Your code doesn't handle the case: it simply plows forward, pretending it acquired the lock.  So, suppose `trylock()` doesn't lock the mutex.  What happens?

```
pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);  // Might fail (i.e., not lock the mutex)
read_c = 1;                            // Modifying shared state (Wrong!)
pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);   // Unlocking a mutex (Wrong!)
```

Then there's the question of how the code should handle `trylock()` failing.  If you can't answer this question, then the default answer is "use `lock()`".

In the reader thread, you can't use `trylock()` because you *have* to lock the mutex:

```
int r = pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
if (r != 0) {
    // Uh... what are we supposed to do here?  Try again?
} else {
    read_c = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
}
```

In the writer thread, there's no point in using `trylock()`:

```
int r = pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
if (r != 0) {
    // Okay, just try again next loop...
} else {
    if (read_c) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
    }
}
```

However, this is entirely pointless.  The only reason `trylock()` will fail in the writer thread is if the reader thread owns the lock, which only happens if it is currently in the process of setting `read_c = 1;`.  So you might as well wait for it to finish, since you know you're going to exit anyway (why write more output after you know that the user has signaled your program to stop?)

Just use `lock()`.  You'll use `lock()` 99% of the time, and `trylock()` is for the other 1%.

<sup>1</sup>: The `lock()` function can fail, but this usually means you've misused the mutex.

### Misconceptions about `lock()` and `trylock()`

You said this about `trylock()`:

> If i have another thread accessing the variable `read_input` then will it be appropriate to use it?

I think there is a very fundamental misunderstanding here about the nature of mutexes.  If another thread weren't accessing the variable at the same time, then you wouldn't need a mutex *at all.*

Suppose you're doing important work at the office, and you need to use the photocopier.  Only one person can use the photocopier at a time.  You go to the photocopier and someone's already using it.

1. If you wait in line until it's your turn, then that's `lock()`.
2. If you give up and go back to your desk, then that's `trylock()`.  (Your program actually ignores the return code for `trylock()`, so you basically start mashing buttons on the photocopier even if someone else is using it.)

Now imagine that it takes one minute to use the photocopier, only two people ever use the photocopier, and they only use the photocopier once every twenty years.

1. If you use `lock()`, then you wait in line for *at most* one minute before using the photocopier.
2. If you use `trylock()`, then you give up and go back to your desk and wait twenty years before trying the photocopier again.

It doesn't make any sense to use `trylock()`, does it?  Are your threads so impatient that they can't spend even one minute in line once every twenty years?

Now your boss comes down and said, "Where is that report I asked you to photocopy?"  And you say, "Well, I went to the photocopier six years ago but someone was using it."

The numbers (one minute every twenty years) are based on [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), where it notes that locking/unlocking a mutex is about 25ns.  So if we pretend that it takes one minute to lock and then unlock a mutex, then `sleep(1)` causes the thread to wait for twenty years.

Comment: Why is there no necessity to flush the buffer when we do `sleep(0);` ? The buffer is flushed out on its own

Comment: Also , why is the use of `trylock` wrong in this case? If i have another thread accessing the variable `read_input` then will it be appropriate to use it?

Comment: 'trylock() is for the other 1%.' - in 30+ years of multithreading development, I've never been tempted to poll a mutex, ever.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich. That was very helpful. I have updated my code to add another `ythread` similar to `xthread`  In that case `trylock` would me apt ? I mean in this case there's a possibility that the other thread was reading the value that's why the `try` failed. So using a trylock  would ensure printing is continued. ?

Comment: @SuvP: It's still wrong.  As an exercise, could you try to figure out one or two reasons why `trylock()` is still wrong?  I'll post the answers after a while.  Hint: Try to figure out what happens if you use `lock()` instead.

Comment: Wait, Ill update the code with the most recent one. I got your point  that if i don't handle the failed trylock I should not be using it. I  am better wit lock itself

Comment: @SuvP: Try answering this question: What happens if both writer threads try to lock the mutex?  Is it okay if this happens?