# `pthread_mutex_trylock` and `pthread_mutex_lock` behaviour

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813984/does-sleep-interfere-with-scanf) question.

In that code, when I was not using `fflush(stdout)` output was not flushed to the screen when I kept `sleep(1)`.

```
#define S sleep(0)
```

---

```
void* xThread_fn(void* arg)
{
while(1)
    {
    S;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&read_c_mutex);
        if(!read_c)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            printf(" X");
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    fflush(stdout); <---THIS ONE HERE
    }

}
```

But when I keep `sleep(0)` there is no need for `fflush(stdout)`, the output is properly updated on `stdout`. Why is this so?

**Q1.** Why should the presence of `sleep(0)` cause any change in the way output is flushed?

If i modify the code as follows (to track execution),

```
#define S sleep(1)

int read_c = 0;
pthread_mutex_t read_c_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* inputThread_fn(void* arg)
{
printf("%p is Input\n",pthread_self());
char inputChar;
int i = 0;
while(1)
{
    S;
    printf("\nChecking input");
    scanf("%c",&inputChar);
    if(inputChar=='C' || inputChar == 'c')
    {
     pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
     printf("%p has lock %d\n",pthread_self(),i);
     read_c = 1;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);       
     printf("%p has UNlockED %d\n",pthread_self(),i++);
     printf("%p is Gone!\n",pthread_self());
     fflush(stdout);
     pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}
}

void* xThread_fn(void* arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%p is X\n",pthread_self());
    while(1)
    {
     S;
     printf("X trying for a lock\n");
     pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
     printf("%p has lock %d\n",pthread_self(),i);
     if(!read_c)
     {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
      printf("%p has UNlockED %d\n",pthread_self(),i++);
      printf("X\n");
      fflush(stdout);
     } 
     else
     {
      printf("%p is Gone!\n",pthread_self());   
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
      fflush(stdout);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
     }
    }
}

void* yThread_fn(void* arg)
{
 printf("%p is Y\n",pthread_self());
 int i = 0;
 while(1)
 {
  S;
  printf("Y trying for a lock\n");
  pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);
  printf("%p has lock %d\n",pthread_self(),i);
  if(!read_c)
  {
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
   printf("%p has UNlockED %d\n",pthread_self(),i++);
   printf("Z\n");
   fflush(stdout);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%p is Gone!\n",pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
  }
}
```

a sample output is

```
0xb6700b70 is Input
0xb6f01b70 is Y
0xb7702b70 is X

Checking inputY trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 0
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 0
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 0
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 0
X
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 1
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 1
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 1
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 1
X
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 2
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 2
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 2
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 2
X
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 3
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 3
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 3
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 3
X
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 4
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 4
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 4
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 4
X
c
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 5
0xb6f01b70 has UNlockED 5
Z
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 5
0xb7702b70 has UNlockED 5
X
0xb6700b70 has lock 0
0xb6700b70 has UNlockED 0
0xb6700b70 is Gone!
Y trying for a lock
0xb6f01b70 has lock 6
0xb6f01b70 is Gone!
X trying for a lock
0xb7702b70 has lock 6
0xb7702b70 is Gone!
```

**Q2.** I have made use of `pthread_mutex_trylock()` because I wanted the code to proceed in the while loop till it acquires a lock to check the value of `read_c`. The same appears to be achieved with `pthread_mutex_lock();`. That confuses me more. With `pthread_mutex_trylock();` *too*, the output always be like this? One `X` followed by one `Z`. Won't there be a situation where it might be like `X` `X` `Z` `X` (Provided the thread is switched by the OS and ythread tried for a lock and failed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the "trylock" question.

`pthread_mutex_trylock` only attempts to lock the mutex. If someone else has the mutex locked, it will just return an error and keep running. Since you're not checking the return value you might touch the data that is protected by the mutex without holding the mutex.

Your code is equivalent to not having any mutexes at all.

`pthread_mutex_trylock` should only be used in situations where you for some very special reason can't wait for a lock and will fall back to a different behavior when acquiring the mutex has failed. Calling it without checking the return value is always a bug.

To be perfectly correct, you should check the return value of `pthread_mutex_lock` too. But you can most often get away with not doing that. You can never get away with not checking the return value of trylock.

Comment: Okay. So it's wrong here right (In `inputThread_fn`)? 
`pthread_mutex_trylock(&read_c_mutex);`
`printf("%p has lock %d\n",pthread_self(),i);`
`read_c = 1;`
`pthread_mutex_unlock(&read_c_mutex);` Here I try for a lock If i don't get it I can still modify the data . So i need a `_lock` not `_trylock`. But if I am just reading the data(as in `xthread_fn` and `yThread_fn`) won't `trylock` be sufficient in that case?

Comment: Simple response to that is: Do not use trylock unless you really really really understand what problem it solves. In most cases it's not the droids you're looking for. In practice in your particular case I'm pretty sure you're on a cache coherent architecture and it would be adequate to not have any mutex at all and any function call would make the compiler not cache the value of the global variable since the reads and writes to it are atomic (and it's just a boolean anyway). That would break all the standards but would probably work.

Comment: Art, this is bad advice you are giving to concurrently access a global without locking! So let me append to your last sentence the word "sometimes" ...

Comment: @alk It's not advice. It's an explanation of why it happens to work in his particular case. He could be calling empty functions instead of pthread_mutex* and the code would still work (it might not work without the function calls though or on a different architecture).

Comment: for all "he" replace "She";

Answer (score 1):

When sleep is called processes is context switched out (scheduled out).
sleep(0) means you are not sleeping really. So process continues to execute.
Printf uses stdout which is buffered. So whatever you print goes into that ouput buffer and later on flushed onto terminal(screen).
When process sleeps buffer is not flushed so you do not get output unless you do explicit flush. If you do not sleep process gets a chance to do flush buffer and immediately you get output.
Whenever you use any blocking calls or sleeping behavior in program you will find this behavior of printf. If you use fprintf(stderr,"your string") then it will always print irrespective of whether you sleep or not.